# How do you use the knowledge from HtDP to ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm, software-design

I'm currently taking the course "How to Code: Simple Data" (https://www.edx.org/course/how-code-simple-data-ubcx-htc1x) which is based on the book "How to Design Programs" (https://htdp.org/2018-01-06/Book/).

If you have taken this course (or read the book), can you share how you used the recipes in designing a React program? A concrete example will be very helpful.

TIA.